# Do these areas have any special meaning or name?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, circles, quadrilateral

I was just toying around with circles and squares.

Do the red areas in the picture have any special meaning somehow?

[image]

Comment: +1 for "toying around". Not that I know of, and I doubt it. You can nest those figures so that they grow and shrink and have fun calculating various dimensions and areas.{1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take both circles of same radius **r**, then you can compare the areas of red parts in both figures:
In fig 1: $$A(square)=(2r)^2=4r^2$$
$$A(circle)=\pi r^2$$

> $$A(red part)=4r^2-\pi r^2 =(4-\pi)r^2$$

In fig 2:
$$A(circle)=\pi r^2$$
diagonal of square=2r, its side will be $r \sqrt 2$
$$A(square)={(r \sqrt 2}^2)=2r^2$$

> $$A(red part)=\pi r^2-2r^2=(\pi -2)r^2$$

So, as such there's no definite relation or *special meaning* between their areas.
Name you ask, may be there's none specifically.